# What does the having count(*) > 1 refer to in this query?

Tags: sql-server, count

I've been trying to learn SQL by working through the book 'SQL Practice Problems' by Sylvia Moestl Vasilik, and wanted to make sure I understood what this specific query was doing:

The question is: “Janet Leverling, one of the salespeople, has come to you with a request. She thinks that she accidentally double-entered a line item on an order, with a different ProductID, but the same quantity. She remembers that the quantity was 60 or more. Show all the OrderIDs with line items that match this, in order of OrderID”

Here's a link to the OrderDetails table: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=33b578a3edd85c7a1bb09d593e1330bc

The answer given in the book is

```
SELECT
    OrderID
FROM
    OrderDetails
WHERE 
    Quantity >= 60
GROUP BY
    Quantity, orderid
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

Does this query just output instances where both quantity and orderid are repeated?

Thanks and sorry if I posted this question in a stupid way.

Comment: It answers that question - but for everyone, not just janet. It finds item rows where quantity >= 60. Groups those together by quantity and order to find items within orders that have the same quantity (>= 60). And then counts those rows and, after counting, filters for those rows where the count > 1 (which is a potential duplicate). To actually "see" this, remove the having clause and add the count to the select list so you can see the count.

Comment: To help understand a query it is often useful to go find a "thing" that should be returned and one that shouldn't be returned, look at the actual row contents, and then run the aggregating query with the having clause and without (while including the actual aggregate). Takes some time to learn these sql tricks.

Answer (score 2):

Try some of these selects in your db fiddle so you can visually see what is happening at each step.

```
Select
  * --just so you can see everything and get a visual
  From OrderDetails
  Where Quantity >= 60





Select
  Quantity, OrderID, count(*) as OrderCount --visually see how many of these orders have a count greater than 1
  From OrderDetails
  Where Quantity >= 60
  group by Quantity, orderid




Select
  Quantity, OrderID --the aggregate conditions dont need to be in the select to be referenced. im including the quantity in the select just so you can see that as well
  From OrderDetails
  Where Quantity >= 60
  group by Quantity, orderid
  having COUNT(*) >1 --having is like a where clause but for an aggregate value. read this like 'get all orders that have an aggregate count of more than 1
```